# ¿How do I save SurfaceView's state?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I have a game that uses a class that extends from `SurfaceView` to show its stuff, it's all ok until I press the "Home" button and then return to the Activity, because it's all like I would started the app again, when i have only paused it, I know why is this occurring, but I don´t know how to "save" the state of the class.

My class constructor:

```
public GameSurface(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    thread = new SurfaceThread(this);//<-the gameloop
    //irrelevant game things like sprites and stuff
}
```

"SurfaceDestroyed" method:

```
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    thread.terminateSurface();//it just calls thread.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the relevant code within this class? Like it's constructor, onCreate, onChange and onDestroyed methods?

Comment: This is not the standard Android behavior, can you check if don't have any code that kill the Activity or the App in onResume() ?

Comment: @Nerdizzle It extends from `SurfaceView` so it does not have "onChange" method, if you talked about "SurfaceDestroyed" i've just edited it.

Comment: @victorleduc Nope, in the Activity's onResume i just check if the gamesurface is not null and its thread is not terminated then its initializated again and it calls "thread.start()"(again), if its not terminated it calls to "notify();", method. To do this i've helped from this link:  http://https417.blogspot.com/2012/08/threading-surfaceview-in-android.html

Comment: And where do you initialize your surfaceview

Comment: @RamIndani In the Activity's onCreate.

Comment: Then it will get recreated when activity starts again. as onStop() is called when you press home key and as per activity life cycle it calls onCreate() once activity reaches onStop() see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: try serializing your class and then store it using something like this 
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("yourView", yourView);
} I haven't tested this code

Comment: @RamIndani I've already tried it and it still does not work.

Comment: Is there any error that you get when you store serialized instance of surfaceView or it simply doesn't work?

Comment: In the logcat, it appears this error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name =  (my GameSurface class))

Comment: i don't know if it will work or not but i thought if you can try adding external storage permissions to manifest, its just guess as its IOException <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />